# Javascript- Almacenar datos de longitud y latitud

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy intentando usar la api de windy para dar los datos del clima segun la ubicacion del usuario. La ubicacion la puedo obtener y ver en la consola usando `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` pero como puedo almacenar en una variable la latitud y longitud?

por las dudas copio el codigo de la api que estoy usando:

```js
windyInit(options, windyAPI => {

    const { map } = windyAPI;

    L.popup()
        .setLatLng([-34.8, -58.4])
        .setContent('Hola mundo')
        .openOn(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    windyInit(options, windyAPI => {

        const { map } = windyAPI;

        L.popup()
            .setLatLng([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
            .setContent('Hola mundo')
            .openOn(map);
    });
}, error => console.error(error));
```